# how to filter users by assigned license using ms-graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying this request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?
$filter=assignedLicenses/any(d:d/skuid eq 28d45cd1-ad8b-15cd-a9e1-52e6a5c24328)
```

But I get this error:

BadRequest - ')' or ',' expected at position 71 in 'assignedLicenses/any(d: d/skuid eq 28d45cd1-ad8b-15cd-a9e1-52e6a5c24328'.

Am I doing anything wrong? is this query possible?

Answer (score 8):

Just an update that this is now a supported API call.  The correct syntax is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq e578b273-6db4-4691-bba0-8d691f4da603)
```

e578b273-6db4-4691-bba0-8d691f4da603 is Faculty A3 SKU in this example

Answer (score 2):

In general, only those properties where the documentation says "supports $filter" can be filtered.

E.g. on the [`user`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user) object, `accountEnabled` can be filtered.

Since the `assignedLicenses` property doesn't say it, and the [`assignedLicense` resource type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/assignedlicense) doesn't have it documented on the `skuId` property, I don't think you can perform that query.

Comment: I could not find such information on the Microsoft Graph documentation https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users. However I found it on the AzureAD Graph doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity. I suppose it's valid in this case.

Comment: I don't know of any documentation that states which properties support filtering, only that the "supports $filter" statement is present only on some properties.

Comment: I think that's poor from MS to not provide a clean API driven way to get report-worthy data. Asking which users have license X for auditing/reporting would be a valid concern from a business perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(s:s/skuId eq 28d45cd1-ad8b-15cd-a9e1-52e6a5c24328)
```

For more reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-using-lambda-operators

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar on "beta" version of GRAPH API. I need to filter by assignedPlan.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?&$filter=assignedPlans/any(d:d/service eq 'SharePoint')](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?&$filter=assignedPlans/any(d:d/service%20eq%20'SharePoint'))

and this is the error message which I got:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Complex query on property assignedPlans is not supported.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "c3fad564-e61d-4066-8bef-548afghtyu",
        "date": "2018-12-10T16:43:36"
    }
}
}
```

So i guess that there is no option to prefilter users by assignedLicenses or Plan.
At least not yet...

Comment: You need to include the consitencylevel eventual header